# How do I get an equation as a string?

Tags: octave, equation

I have an equation that is used to make an isosurface which is then saved into a file and I need to keep track of which equations belong to which file. Therefore I want to label the files my Octave script produces with the equation that produced them without labeling them all by hand.
This is my code right now:

```
clf;

function [f, v] = doiso(dodraw)
  m = 3;
  dim = -m:0.1:m;
  if (dodraw > 0)
    dim = -m:0.6:m;
  endif
  [x,y,z] = meshgrid(dim, dim, dim);
  func = cos(x) .* sin(y) + cos(y) .* sin(z) + cos(z) .* sin(x);
  if (dodraw > 0)
    isosurface(func, 0);
  else
    [f, v] = isosurface(func, 0);
  endif
endfunction

#draw
doiso(1);
axis equal;
title("isosurface() of the function");

#saveq
[f, v] = doiso(0);
vertface2obj(v, f, strcat("objs/", int2str(time * 1000), "out.obj"));
```

The saved file should have names like `cos(x) . sin(y) + cos(y) . sin(z) + cos(z) . sin(x) 1513441860368.obj` where the long number is a timestamp and the expression containing sin and cos is the equation that produced the file (same as in the code). Invalid chars will have to be removed or replaced in the file name string.

No online resource seems to mention printing an equation; only printing numbers or solving equations.

Comment: maybe I could replace the invalid chars? The point is that I can't get Octave to give my any string representation of the equation at all.

Comment: I think saving the formula as filename is a bad idea and I would rather add a string to your saved file with the formula

Comment: What Andy said. Or, better yet, if what you really need is a way to associate a function with its equation, simply create an external table you can refer to programmatically. E.g. `Equations.f1 = "cos(x)"; Equations.f2 = "sin(x)";` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is using [`func2str()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Function-Handles.html#XREFfunc2str):

> `func2str (fcn_handle)`
>
> Return a string containing the name of the function referenced by the function handle `fcn_handle`.

You will have to create an anonymous function for your equation. For example,

```matlab
> f = @(x,y,z) cos(x) .* sin(y) + cos(y) .* sin(z) + cos(z) .* sin(x);
> eqn = func2str(f);
> fprintf(stdout, '%s\n', eqn)
@(x, y, z) cos (x) .* sin (y) + cos (y) .* sin (z) + cos (z) .* sin (x)
```

As you can see, the above code creates the string `eqn` containing the expression of the function `f`.
You can then manipulate the string to get something more reasonable as a file name. Here's a simple example:

```matlab
> fname = regexprep(strjoin(strsplit(eqn(11:end)), ''), '[().*+]', '_')
fname = cos_x___sin_y__cos_y___sin_z__cos_z___sin_x_
```

Here `strjoin(strsplit(str), '')` removes all whitespace from the string `str`. The function `regexprep()` uses regex substitutions to replace the "undesired" characters with an underscore.
You can of course have more elaborate manipulations, such as changing `*` to `_TIMES_` or whatever you prefer.
More about manipulating strings [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Manipulating-Strings.html).